# Weights argument in glmer() when predicting proportion data: why is it needed when all weights are around the same?

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

What do the `weights` argument in `glmer` refer to? I used sample sizes as `weights` with `glm`, but here I am not sure. The variance of sample sizes is quite low, but including it or not in `glmer` gives me a huge difference. For example, in the dataset below, using only one independent variable, the difference in results is huge (estimate, BIC, p.value). Does anyone have experience using weights in `glmer` and confirm if it works as expected or if I am doing it right?

[A thread on r-sig-mixed models](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel/10160) and in github pages, there seems to be an issue with `weights` argument in `glmer`, but since my knowledge of mixed-models is only weeks old, I am not able to follow it.

My data:

```r
    cv <- structure(list(name = c("AlfF", "AndH", "AntH", "BerG",  
           "BerR", "FreZ", "GerB","GerT", "GueS", "GueV", "HanN",  
           "HeiW", "JakW","KarN", "KerG", "KlaS", "ManS", "MarS",  
           "SilN", "TheG", "UweP","WerT", "AlfF", "AndH", "AntH",  
           "BerG", "BerR", "FreZ", "GerB","GerT", "GueS", "GueV",  
           "HanN", "HeiW", "JakW", "KarN", "KerG", "KlaS", 
           "ManS", "MarS", "SilN", "TheG", "UweP", "WerT", 
           "AlfF", "AndH", "AntH", "BerG", "BerR", "FreZ", 
           "GerB", "GerT", "GueS", "GueV", "HanN", "HeiW", 
           "JakW", "KarN", "KerG", "KlaS", "ManS", "SilN", 
           "TheG", "UweP", "WerT", "AlfF", "AndH", "AntH", 
           "BerG", "BerR", "FreZ", "GerB", "GerT", "GueS", 
           "GueV", "HanN", "HeiW", "JakW", "KarN", "KerG", 
           "KlaS", "ManS", "SilN", "TheG", "UweP", "WerT", 
           "AlfF", "AndH", "AntH", "BerK", "BerR", "ChrG", 
           "FraR", "FreZ", "GerB", "GerB", "GerT", "GueS", 
           "GueV", "HanN", "HeiW", "JakW", "KlaS", "ManS", 
           "MarH", "PetS", "SilN", "TheG", "UweP", "WerT", 
           "AlfF", "AndH", "BerK", "BerR", "ChrG", "FraR", 
           "FreZ", "GerB", "GerB", "GerT", "GueV", "HanN", 
           "HeiW", "JakW", "KlaS", "ManS", "MarH", "PetS", 
           "PetW", "SilN", "SveR", "UweP", "WerT", "AlfF", 
           "AndH", "AntH", "BerK", "BerR", "ChrG", "FraR", 
           "FreZ", "GerB", "GerB", "GerT", "GueS", "GueV", 
           "HanN", "HeiW", "JakW", "KlaS", "ManS", "MarH", 
           "MicH", "PetS", "SilN", "SveR", "UweP", "WerT"), 
           prop_yes = c(0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.778, 0, 0.05, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 
    0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.111, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0, 0.111, 
    0, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.333, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 
    0.182, 0, 0.1, 0.364, 0.1, 0.3, 0.375, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 
    0.667, 0.2, 0.571, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2,  
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.75, 0.2, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.222, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6,  
    0, 0, 0.1, 0.167, 0.333, 0, 0.222, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.1, 0),  
    size = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             19L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 
             10L, 20L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L,  
             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 
             10L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 
             9L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
             10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 10L,  
             10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L,  
             10L), tmean_winter = c(-3.83, -4.31, -3.97, -5.21,  
             -4.6, -4.09, -4.05, -4.09, -4.85, -4.48, -4.77, 
             -6.66, -4.16, -4.68, -4.48, -5.07, -3.83, -4.28, 
             -4.79,  -4.83, -4.09, -4.43, 2.36, 1.47, 2.13, 1.09,  
             1.93, 2.26, 2.28, 1.98, 1.66, 1.3, 1.69, -1.01, 
             2.22, 1.89, 2, 1.23, 2.33, 2.1, 1.68, 1.66, 1.95, 
             1.38, 1.61, 0.86, 1.82, 0.48, 1.45, 1.74, 1.5, 1.78,  
             1.14, 0.65, 1.17, -1.59, 1.69, 1.55, 1.44, 0.65, 
             1.59, 1.16, 1.14, 1.23, 0.81, -1.53, -2.61, -1.52, 
             -2.7, -1.77, -1.54, -1.68, -1.32, -2.16, -2.82, 
             -1.95, -4.56, -1.57, -1.77, -1.76, -2.55, -1.51, 
             -1.98, -2.05, -1.97, -2.62, -4.48, -5.25, -4.04, 
             -4.92, -4.59, -5.34, -5.09, -4.12, -4.36, -5.23, 
             -4.94, -4.7, -5.28, -4.55, -7.07, -4.18, -5.17, 
             -4.56, -4.56, -4.74, -4.58, -4.62, -5.08, -5.25, 
             -1.87, -2.67, -2.84, -2.47, -3.11, -2.3, -2.01, 
             -2.05, -2.96, -2.57, -2.75, -2.54, -4.18, -2.07, 
             -3.04, -1.81, -2.39, -2.24, -2.75, -2.75, -2.79, 
             -2.44, -2.85, -0.35, -1.47, -0.43, -1.02, -0.76, 
             -1.23, -1.57, -0.48, -0.65, -1.18, -0.58, -0.92, 
             -1.58, -1.07, -4.05, -0.52, -2.1, -0.36, -0.75, 
             -1.04, -0.67, -1.05, -1.81, -0.61, -1.64)), .Names =  
             c("name", "prop_yes", "size", "tmean_winter"), 
             row.names = c(NA, -158L), class = "data.frame")

    glmer(prop_yes~tmean_winter+(1|name), family='binomial', 
           data=cv)
    glmer(prop_yes~tmean_winter+(1|name), family='binomial', 
           data=cv, weights=size)
```

Comment: I think this is a computing question (voted to close) but, in the mean time, the weights are not sampling weights or anything like that and have nothing specifically to do with the mixed model. In a binomial glm, if you use the success proportions as the outcome variable, the weights are the number of trials used to generate each proportion. If `y` is the outcome, `x` is the predictor and `n` is the number of trials, `glm( I(y/n) ~ x, family=binomial, weights=n )` fits the exact same model as `glm( cbind(y,n-y) ~ x, family=binomial)`.

Comment: This case is ambiguous / debatable, but it seems to me the issue is confusion about the underlying ideas that it driving the confusion about the code. Ie, we need to clarify the ideas to resolve the issue. If true, that would mean that the Q can stay here (although it would require someone familiar w/ R to answer the Q effectively). I would say that if this Q doesn't receive a suitable answer w/i a reasonable period of time, it should then be migrated to SO.

Comment: @gung, I parsed this as asking what a particular argument in a particular function does. That's a programming question to me. I don't see how there could be an answer that is much more than a excerpt of the documentation or a chunk of code. Either way, I don't feel strongly enough about it to try to convince anyone. My vote's been cast. Cheers.

Comment: Alea iacta est, @Macro. I'm pretty much 50-50 here, but I can see it both ways & defer to the OP's (presumed) preference for CV. If it ends up migrated, I'll be OK w/ it.

Comment: @Macro Thank you for your comments. I asked the Q here since to me it felt more like a statistics Q than programming. May be I did not word it right then? In my case, it is the number of bee colonies in an apiary that are infected that I used as weights and the proportion of the number of infected colonies as the independent variable. In this sense, my usage of number of colonies tested as `weights` in a `glm` would be right, or?

Comment: @gung Thanks for the edits. Formatted code is certainly the way.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this seems to be an old topic, and the main discussion was whether it is code or computing question, I think I could try to answer this question in some way, at least. But also with some uncertainty, though (maybe someone else could jump in with more detailed or mathematically founded answer).

Disclaimer: I am no methematician or something similar, and I also have my issues with understanding answers like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246913/the-theory-behind-the-weights-argument-in-r-when-using-lm?rq=1). But I am "just" an ecologist and can just talk from my practical experience point of view. Therefore, my answer is just a weak try to explain the practical part.

Following [Zuur et. al (2009)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-87458-6), you should include the basis of each proportion as a weight in your glm. I don't see any reason why this does not account for a glmer.
How I would explain this point for myself, is, that the basis of your proportion matters for the "power" of your estimation.

Pretend you have a survival rate of 20 %. It matters whether it is 20 % of 5 (which means **one** observation), or whether it is 20 % of 100 (which means 20 observations). The probability of one false positive is much higher than of 20.
Thus, it seems natural, that the outcome should be different between both versions.

However, what I don't know, and why I actually found this question is, whether the R function really considers this point or whether the `weight` only matters in case of imbalanced observations (i.e., in one case the basis is 100 and in another it is just 50), and if I could leave out the `weight` parameter in case I have a balanced situation.

It would be nice, if one with more profound mathematical or informatics background could add something about that.