# The theory behind the weights argument in R when using lm()

Tags: r, linear-model, weighted-regression

After a year in grad school, my understanding of "weighted least squares" is the following: let $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{X}$ be some $n \times p$ design matrix, $\boldsymbol\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be a parameter vector, $\boldsymbol\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an error vector such that $\boldsymbol\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \sigma^2\mathbf{V})$, where $\mathbf{V} = \text{diag}(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n)$ and $\sigma^2 > 0$. Then the model 
$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta + \boldsymbol\epsilon$$
under the assumptions is called the "weighted least squares" model. The WLS problem ends up being to find 
$$\begin{equation}
\arg\min_{\boldsymbol \beta}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta\right)^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta\right)\text{.}
\end{equation}$$
Suppose $\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & \dots & y_n\end{bmatrix}^{T}$, $\boldsymbol\beta = \begin{bmatrix} \beta_1 & \dots & \beta_p\end{bmatrix}^{T}$, and
$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
x_{21} & \cdots & x_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{np}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_{1}^{T} \\
\mathbf{x}_{2}^{T} \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{x}_{n}^{T}
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
Then, observe $\mathbf{x}_i^{T}\boldsymbol\beta\in \mathbb{R}^1$, so $$\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1-\mathbf{x}_{1}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta \\
y_2-\mathbf{x}_{2}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta \\
\vdots \\
y_n-\mathbf{x}_{n}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
This gives
$$\begin{align}
(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta)^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1} &= \begin{bmatrix}
y_1-\mathbf{x}_{1}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta &y_2-\mathbf{x}_{2}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta &
\cdots & 
y_n-\mathbf{x}_{n}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta
\end{bmatrix}\text{diag}(v_1^{-1}, v_2^{-1}, \dots, v_n^{-1}) \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
v_1^{-1}(y_1-\mathbf{x}_{1}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta) &v_2^{-1}(y_2-\mathbf{x}_{2}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta) &
\cdots & 
v_n^{-1}(y_n-\mathbf{x}_{n}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$ 
thus giving $$\begin{equation}
\arg\min_{\boldsymbol \beta}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta\right)^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta\right)
\end{equation} = \arg\min_{\boldsymbol \beta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_i^{-1}(y_i-\mathbf{x}^{T}_i\boldsymbol\beta)^2\text{.}$$
$\boldsymbol\beta$ is estimated using $$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{y}\text{.}$$
This is the extent of the knowledge I am familiar with. I was never taught how $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ should be chosen, although it seems that, judging by [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/352), that usually $\text{Var}(\boldsymbol\epsilon) = \text{diag}(\sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2, \dots, \sigma^2_n)$, which makes intuitive sense. (Give highly variable weights less weight in the WLS problem, and give observations with less variability more weight.)

What I am particularly curious about is how `R` handles weights in the `lm()` function when weights are assigned to be integers. From using `?lm`:

> Non-`NULL` weights can be used to indicate that different observations
>   have different variances (with the values in weights being inversely
>   proportional to the variances); or equivalently, when the elements of
>   weights are positive integers $w_i$, that each response $y_i$ is the mean
>   of $w_i$ unit-weight observations (including the case that there are $w_i$
>   observations equal to $y_i$ and the data have been summarized).

I've re-read this paragraph several times, and it makes no sense to me. Using the framework that I developed above, suppose I have the following simulated values:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2)
y <- c(0.25, 0.75, 0.85)
weights <- c(50, 85, 75)

lm(y~x, weights = weights)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, weights = weights)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.3495       0.2834
```

Using the framework I've developed above, how are these parameters derived? Here's my attempt at doing this by hand: assuming $\mathbf{V} = \text{diag}(50, 85, 75)$, we have
$$\begin{align}&\begin{bmatrix}
\hat\beta_0 \\
\hat\beta_1
\end{bmatrix} = \\
&\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\text{diag}(1/50, 1/85, 1/75)\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{T} \right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\text{diag}(1/50, 1/85, 1/75)\begin{bmatrix}
0.25 \\
0.75 \\
0.85
\end{bmatrix} \end{align}$$
and doing this in `R` gives (note that invertibility doesn't work in this case, so I used a generalized inverse):

```
X <- matrix(rep(1, times = 6), byrow = T, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
V_inv <- diag(c(1/50, 1/85, 1/75))
y <- c(0.25, 0.75, 0.85)

library(MASS)
ginv(t(X) %*% V_inv %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% V_inv %*% y

         [,1]
[1,] 0.278913
[2,] 0.278913
```

These don't match the values from the `lm()` output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix $X$ should be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
not
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Also, your `V_inv` should be `diag(weights)`, not `diag(1/weights)`.

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2)
y <- c(0.25, 0.75, 0.85)
weights <- c(50, 85, 75)
X <- cbind(1, x)

> solve(t(X) %*% diag(weights) %*% X, t(X) %*% diag(weights) %*% y)
       [,1]
  0.3495122
x 0.2834146
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the incorrect design matrix, especially! I'm quite rusty on this material. So, as one last question, does this mean that $\text{Var}(\boldsymbol\epsilon) = \text{diag}(1/\text{weights})$ in the WLS assumptions?

Comment: Yes, although the weights only have to be proportional to 1/variance, not necessarily equal. For example, if you use `weights <- c(50, 85, 75)/2` in your example, you get the same result.

Answer (score 5):

To answer this more concisely, the weighted least squares regression using `weights` in `R` makes the following assumptions: suppose we have `weights = c(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n)`. Let $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{X}$ be a $n \times p$ design matrix, $\boldsymbol\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$ be a parameter vector, and $\boldsymbol\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an error vector with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and variance matrix $\sigma^2\mathbf{V}$, where $\sigma^2 > 0$. Then, $$\mathbf{V} = \text{diag}(1/w_1, 1/w_2, \dots, 1/w_n)\text{.}$$
Following the same steps of the derivation in the original post, we have
$$\begin{align}
\arg\min_{\boldsymbol \beta}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta\right)^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta\right)&= \arg\min_{\boldsymbol \beta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1/w_i)^{-1}(y_i-\mathbf{x}^{T}_i\boldsymbol\beta)^2 \\
&= \arg\min_{\boldsymbol \beta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i(y_i-\mathbf{x}^{T}_i\boldsymbol\beta)^2
\end{align}$$
and $\boldsymbol\beta$ is estimated using $$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{y}$$
from the [GLS assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares#Method_outline).